# Google charts options title

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to print in the google charts title the current month

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var d = new Date();
var month = document.write("The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);


// Set chart options
  var options = { 'title':'',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};
```

Comment: And what is stopping you? `'title':"The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()],`

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work, the whole chart disappeared

Comment: remember the comma: `'title':"The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()],`<<<<<< - and press F12 to see the console error

Comment: Yes, i've added the comma. still no chart.

Comment: Errors in the console? And you can certainly not use document.write after loading. `var d = new Date();
var monthText = The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()];
  var options = { 'title':monthText,`

Comment: i think its because you used document.write() add it to an HTML element and print it there https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Comment: Yes ! It works now ! Many thanks !

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It is highly localised to your issue

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `document.write` and just assign the desired month to a variable and use it in the title

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var d = new Date();
var month = "The current month is " + monthNames[d.getMonth()];

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: month
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="piechart" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Come ON. Now it cannot be deleted. It is not a question worth answering and your answer was already in the comments